# embulk-output-bigquery mode difference between replace and delete_in_advance

Tags: google-bigquery, migration

https://github.com/embulk/embulk-output-bigquery

I'm using this plugin very well. But I have something being curious. What is difference between delete_in_advance and replace in mode?

Situation is like below.
I'm migrationing to bigquery. But the job is full dump so I think delete_in_advance is more closer than replace.
But I got same result about two of both.
Please let me know what is difference.

Comment: Hello 김승환 please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn a about how to ask a good question. Maybe you can provide some code examples of what you have tried to further clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/embulk/embulk-output-bigquery/issues/124#issuecomment-734256930

> delete_in_advance: The table would become empty after (1) and before (2). This is easy implementation, but usually not desired. If another batch which reads the table while embulk is running > with delete_in_advance, the another batch may reads an empty table or a table with a few rows on the gap timing between (1) and (2).
>
> - (1) delete
> - (2) insert
>   replace: In the case of replace, because we use an atomic operation, there is no gap timing which a table becomes empty or with a few rows. The behavior is very expected to build robust data > engineering.
> - (1) creates temp table
> - (2) replace target table with the temp table with an atomic operation
>   replace mode is recommended.